# Highlight and hide duplicate values in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I'm outputting a list of coordinates, and I want to automatically highlight the presence of duplicate coordinates.

```php
<?php

$coords = array(
    "7" => array(
        "x" => array("0" => "395"),
        "y" => array("0" => "81"),
        "z" => array("0" => "17")
    ),
    "14" => array(
        "x" => Array("0" => "115","1" => "531"),
        "y" => Array("0" => "47","1" => "402"),
        "z" => Array("0" => "21","1" => "18")
    ),
    "15" => array(
        "x" => array("0" => "528","1" => "3","2" => "531"),
        "y" => array("0" => "207","1" => "162","2" => "402"),
        "z" => array("0" => "24","1" => "25","2" => "18")
    )
);

foreach ($coords as $index => $xyz){

}
?>
```

Here's what the array looks like.
You'll notice that the coordinates in some positions may be duplicated (ex. id `#14` and `#15`).

So the duplication will need to match on coordinates `x/y/z`, but not on id.

I can not figure out how to get the values of the array as follows, and hide the duplicate:

```
7: 395x81x17
14: 115x47x21
14,15: 531x402x18
15: 528x207x24
15: 3x162x25
```

Comment: what have u tried ?/

Comment: The shape of your data is bad. `$coords = ["14" => [[115,47,21], [531,402,18]], "15" => [...], ...]` is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just make kind of inverted index? Like

```
$inverted_index = [];
foreach ($coords as $index => $xyz){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($xyz['x']); $i++) {
        $hash = sprintf('%sx%sx%s', $xyz['x'][$i], $xyz['y'][$i], $xyz['z'][$i]);
        if(!isset($inverted_index[$hash])) {
            $inverted_index[$hash] = [];
        }
        $inverted_index[$hash][] = $index;
    }
}
```

As result you will get `$inverted_index` which can be used to display what you want to get

```
foreach ($inverted_index as $coords => $index){
    printf("%s: %s\n", implode(',', $index), $coords);
}
```

Or just access all coordinate points with simple `$inverted_index[sprintf('%sx%sx%s', $x, $y, $z)]`.

The solution isn't memory friendly and building index each time isn't good idea but this looks quite simple to implement and use.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I was looking for. Of course, it needs improvement but you have helped me to achieve result.